# A simple graph problem that seems NP complete

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, np-complete

Consider an arbitrary undirected graph where each node $i$ has an arbitrary cost $c_i>0$ and each edge has a weight of 1. The objective is to select a set of edges so that the total weight of the selected edges minus the total cost of the nodes incident to the selected edges is maximized. For example, if edge $(1,2)$ and $(2,3)$ are selected, then the objective value is 1+1-$c_1$-$c_2$-$c_3$. I strongly feel that this problem is NP complete (or NP hard?), but I do not know how to prove or disprove it. It seems hard to reduce from a classic NP complete problem like set cover or independent set problem. Can anyone provide any hint?

Comment: An equivalent formulation is to select a set of vertices and then the score is the number of edges between two vertices in the set minus the total costs of the vertices. This suggests that it might be interesting to look at cliques, which maximise the edges/vertices ratio.